# NSLayoutConstraint that would pin a view to the bottom edge of a superview

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, autolayout

### A reproducible example

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var created = false

   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
      if !created {

         let scrollView = UIScrollView()
         scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
         view.addSubview(scrollView)

         let kidView = UIView()
         kidView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
         kidView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

         scrollView.addSubview(kidView)

         scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         kidView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

         view.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[scrollView]|", options: .AlignAllLeft, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView])
         )
         view.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[scrollView]|", options: .AlignAllLeft, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView])
         )

         kidView.addConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: kidView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: kidView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100),
         ])

         scrollView.addConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: kidView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: kidView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
//            NSLayoutConstraint(item: kidView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
         ])

         created = true
      }
   }

}
```

### Problem

I want to align my custom view to the bottom edge of my `UIScrollView`, but I can only seem to align it to the top, or vertical center.

```
scrollView.addConstraints([
    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: circleContainerView, 
        attribute: .Top, 
        relatedBy: .Equal, 
        toItem: scrollView, 
        attribute: .Top, 
        multiplier: 1, 
        constant: 0),
])
```

[image]

```
scrollView.addConstraints([
    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: circleContainerView, 
        attribute: .CenterY, 
        relatedBy: .Equal, 
        toItem: scrollView, 
        attribute: .CenterY, 
        multiplier: 1, 
        constant: 0),
])
```

[image]

But what I want is to have a picture like this. How do I get there?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ScrollView with auto layout works differently either you can use only one subview by setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` and setting contentSize explicitly.
Or you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and let it find out constraint it self.

In your case you can add an invisible view inside scroll and pin it to top and set its height to `scrollView.bounds.size.height` and then set create constraint with that invisible view

Change your constraint like this

```
scrollView.addConstraints([
    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: circleContainerView, 
        attribute: .Bottom, 
        relatedBy: .Equal, 
        toItem: invisibleView, 
        attribute: .Bottom, 
        multiplier: 1, 
        constant: 0),
])
```

Visit this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html) for more details, read pure auto layout approach

**Update:** your modified code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var created = false

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if !created {

            let scrollView = UIScrollView()
            scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            view.addSubview(scrollView)

            let kidView = UIView()
            kidView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

            scrollView.addSubview(kidView)

            scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            kidView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            scrollView.frame = view.bounds;
            scrollView.contentSize = view.bounds.size

            // Add an invisible view

            let inV = UIView()
            inV.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            inV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            scrollView.addSubview(inV)


            view.addConstraints(
                NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[scrollView]|", options: .AlignAllLeft, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView])
            )
            view.addConstraints(
                NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[scrollView]|", options: .AlignAllLeft, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView])
            )

            var constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: inV, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

            view.addConstraint(constraint)

            constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: inV, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            view.addConstraint(constraint)

            inV.addConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: inV, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 10),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: inV, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.bounds.size.height),
                ])

            //

            kidView.addConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: kidView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 100),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: kidView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 100),
                ])

            view.addConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: kidView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: kidView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: inV, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                ])

            created = true
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this moves the child view all the way up, above the superview. I've updated my question with the full code to reproduce this behaviour, it's only ~40 lines.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I do understand now why there's a need for an extra view, given how auto layout works.