# Controller in ScrollView extending too far

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm building a Login Flow with a `UIScrollView` but I can't figure out why my first view controller (step1VC) is extending further than the screen size. Here are screenshots of the [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sJkR.png) and [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpO2x.png) view controllers.

Looks fine on an iPhone 5, but not 6/6 Plus

Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set up Content
    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    self.contentScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.contentScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(screenSize.width * 3, screenSize.height);

    self.step1VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginStep1ViewController"];
    [self addChildViewController:self.step1VC];
    [self.contentScrollView addSubview:self.step1VC.view];
    [self.step1VC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    self.step2VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginStep2ViewController"];
    self.step2VC.view.x = screenSize.width;
    [self addChildViewController:self.step2VC];
    [self.contentScrollView addSubview:self.step2VC.view];
    [self.step2VC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    self.step3VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginStep3ViewController"];
    self.step3VC.view.x = screenSize.width * 2;
    [self addChildViewController:self.step3VC];
    [self.contentScrollView addSubview:self.step3VC.view];
    [self.step3VC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set constraints to views, add constraints to them, for example to make tagline center and full width, pin tagLine label to left and right of superView, same with title and button.
For title and button you can set there width and height and then can pin them horizontallyCeneter in super view.

And if you are using `AutoLayout` constraints with scrollView then you should know auto layout works bit differently with `UIScrollView` you can check this answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968547/nslayoutconstraint-that-would-pin-a-view-to-the-bottom-edge-of-a-superview/31974345#31974345) and [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) for more details

**Tip**: Add width constraint to stepVcs.View and set its value to scrollView.frame.width